# SWI Prolog equivalence

Tags: loops, prolog

I think this is a really simple question, but I still can´t solve it.

How can I define a logical consequence in both directions in Prolog?

For example my database contains this:

```
need_umbrealla(X) :- rainy(X).
rainy(X) :- need_umbrealla(X).
```

It always results in a permanent loop if I do the request

```
rainy(X).
```

to my interpreter.

What can I do there?

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: What should be the output of `rainy(X)`?

Comment: See [tag:failure-slice]

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The current weather, supposedly :)

Comment: CHR allows you to do things like this; maybe you're thinking in forward-chaining terms instead of Prolog's backward-chaining fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable X that you are declaring as rainy is the same variable that needs an umbrella. What is X? Does the weather need an umbrella?

You could just declare:
`needs_umbrella(X , rainy).`

with the request:

```
needs_umbrella(monday, rainy).  
true

needs_umbrella(monday, sunny).
false
```